# Calculate values from different selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdown, return-value

How to calculate value from different selected dropdown ?
I dont know how to show or set the value subTotal in the html or javascript.

For example, item1 will selected 2 and 1 so for the subtotal it will be 3 and the total at the end will be 3. But if the its selected 1 the total at the end will be 4.

Here my code

HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
 <div class= "row">
  <div class= "col">
   <select class= "item1" onchange="update()">
    <option name ="option" value="0">0</option>
    <option name ="option" value="1">1</option>
    <option name ="option" value="2">2</option>
   </select>
  </div> 
 </div>

 <div class= "row">
  <div class= "col">
   <select class= "item1" onchange="update()">
    <option name ="option" value="0">0</option>
    <option name ="option" value="1">1</option>
    <option name ="option" value="2">2</option>
   </select>
  </div> 
 </div>

  <div class= "col">
   <input name="subTotal1" id="subTotal1" type="text" readonly>
  </div>


 <div class= "row">
  <div class= "col">
   <select class= "item2" onchange="update()">
    <option name ="option" value="0">0</option>
    <option name ="option" value="1">1</option>
    <option name ="option" value="2">2</option>
   </select>
  </div> 
 </div

  <div class= "col">
   <input name="subTotal2" id="subTotal2" type="text" readonly>
  </div>

   <div class= "col">
   <input name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly>
  </div>
</div
```

Javascript:

```
function update() {
 var getAllItem1 = document.querySelectorAll(".item1");
 var subTotal1 = 0;

 getAllItem1.forEach(function(select) {
  var valueItem1 = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  if (valueItem1 != 0) {
   subtotal1 += parseInt(valueItem1);
  }
 });

 document.getElementByID(".subTotal1").value = subtotal1;
}
```

Comment: Your question has a good and complete answer. If you are able, perhaps you could accept it and even up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things wrong here. Your variable `subTotal1` is defined with a capital T, but when you reference it later, it is spelled `subtotal1`. That should be updated to match in all places referenced. Next you've used the `getElementById` method, but spelled it with a capital D. That should be lower case. You also left a `.` in front of the selector name subTotal1. An ID does not need this.

```
function update() {
   var getAllItem1 = document.querySelectorAll(".item1");
   var subTotal1 = 0;

   getAllItem1.forEach(function(select) {
      var valueItem1 = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
      if (valueItem1 != 0) {
          subTotal1 += parseInt(valueItem1);
      }
   });

   document.getElementById("subTotal1").value = subTotal1;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ty38zbq2/)

And since you've tagged this as jQuery, but not used any, I've updated this using it:

```
function update() 
{
   var getAllItem1 = $(".item1");
   var subTotal1 = 0;

   $.each(getAllItem1, function(i, select) {
      var v = $(select).val();
      if (v != 0) 
      {
        subTotal1 += parseInt(v);
      }
   });

   $("#subTotal1").val(subTotal1);
}

$('select.item1').change(update)
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2npt3oar/1/)